# Javascript: Disable textfield don't work

Tags: javascript

I have tried coding some javascript for form that, when user typing certain word then the textfield below will automatically disable.The problem is, when i the tried the code in jsfiddle the code will run smoothly but when i use it in my project, it don't work.
Can anybody explain what wrong with my code.

```
<script>
function matchWord(e){
if(document.getElementById('uname').value.trim === 'Unknown' || document.getElementById('uname').value.trim === 'unknown'){
    document.getElementById('pword').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('response').disabled = true;
    alert('you enter bannned name in the field');
 }
else{
 }
}
document.getElementById('uname').onkeyup = matchWord();
</script>

<html>
   <body>
       Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
       password:<input type="password" name='pword' id='pword' placeholder="password"><br>
       Responsibility:<select id = "response">
                     <option>---Responsibility---</option>
                      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo: `function matchWord` (camelCase) vs `= matchword` (lowercase).

Comment: just fix it but still won't work.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's devtools for errors? One that's possible is explained by "[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)"

Comment: Try putting the Script in the body. Or at least in the <html> tags!
Edit: and give it a <head> tag to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below code works fine for me in all browsers

<html>
   <body>
       Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
       password:<input type="password" name='pword' id='pword' placeholder="password"><br>
       Responsibility:<select id = "response">
                     <option>---Responsibility---</option>
                      </select>
   </body>
   <script>
function matchWord(e){
if(document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'Unknown' || document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'unknown'){
    document.getElementById('pword').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('response').disabled = true;
    alert('you enter bannned name in the field');
 }
else{
 }
}
document.getElementById('uname').addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        matchWord(evt);
    }, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Try to include at least a brief explanation along with a snippet, detailing what's different from the snippet(s) in the question and why you think the revisions are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: Typo `matchword()`, replace it with `matchWord();`

Problem 2: trim is a method! use `document.getElementById('uname').value.trim()` instead.

```js
function matchWord(e) {
  if (document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'Unknown' || document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'unknown') {
    document.getElementById('pword').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('response').disabled = true;
    alert('you enter bannned name in the field');
  }
}
```

```html
Name:
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="matchWord()">
<br> password:
<input type="password" name='pword' id='pword' placeholder="password">
<br> Responsibility:
<select id="response">
  <option>---Responsibility---</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

**First** [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) is not a property, its a method. So, you need to change it from `trim` to `trim()`.

**Second** you need to assign a function to `onkeyup`, not call a function.

```js
function matchWord(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'Unknown' || document.getElementById('uname').value.trim === 'unknown') {
        document.getElementById('pword').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('response').disabled = true;
        alert('you enter bannned name in the field');
    } else {}
}
document.getElementById('uname').onkeyup = matchWord;
```

```html
Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
password:<input type="password" name='pword' id='pword' placeholder="password"><br>
Responsibility:
<select id = "response">
<option>---Responsibility---</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting as eventhanlder of the KeyUp event the results of your function, and you want to set the function itself.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('uname').onkeyup = matchWord;
```

Instead, or add the event handler in the element itself, removing previous line and adding:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="matchWord()">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in the sample you provided.

- First off, names are case-sensitive, so `matchWord` is not the same as `matchword`. Be careful!
- Secondly, you need to use `document.getElementById('uname').onkeyup = matchWord;` to assign the function itself to the event, not the result that it returns.
- Third and final point, the logic in your method is wrong, as you use `trim` instead of `trim()`, which is the exact opposite mistake of the one mentioned above and this returns the function instead of the value. The following snippet works:

```js
function matchWord(e) {
  if (document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'Unknown' ||
    document.getElementById('uname').value.trim() === 'unknown') {
    document.getElementById('pword').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('response').disabled = true;
    alert('you enter bannned name in the field');
  } else {}
}

document.getElementById('uname').onkeyup = matchWord;
```

```html
Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username"><br> password:
<input type="password" name='pword' id='pword' placeholder="password"><br> Responsibility:
<select id="response">
<option>---Responsibility---</option>
</select>
```

Comment: still failed,i think the problem is from my browser. but still thanks.

Comment: @Nexz what browser are you on? This should work perfectly fine in any modern browser...

Comment: it's ok, i have found the answer below. but fyi, i use both chrome and firefox.thanks.

Comment: @Nexz how does this fail exactly, then? What is it that happens when you run it?

Comment: alert not function when i'm typing the name, and also it don't disable the both field below it. I doesn't said your code not work, it still run on code snippet tool but only on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
<script> // stuff </script>
```

in:

```
<html> // here </script>
```